# Css-masking for all browsers?

Tags: html, css, mask

Is there a way to use masks in css which are also working on Firefox?

I can't find a way, but it need be possible.

I found a snippet with `mask: ('mask.svg#mask');` but it won't work!

Answer (score 0):

use 
     -moz-//here goes css code // for mozila firefox
example code
     div{
     background: linear-gradient(top to bottom , black , white);
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top to bottom , black , 
     white);
     }
similarly
     -webkit- for safari browsers.

Answer (score 0):

check out http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ as this is an online tool to help create "clip-path" properties.

You can also check http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path to see a full list of browser support.

Both are pretty good resources.

Comment: These resources only say me that it isn't possible for firefox. I'm searching for a way to use masks also for firefox.